# How can I alter the height of a UIView using CGAffineTransformScale?

Tags: ios, cgaffinetransformscale

Is it possible to change the height of a UIView alone using CGAffineTransformScale?

I do not want to entirely scale my UIView. I just wanted to increase the height alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not use transform. Better to set the frame of the UIView. Since this really change the height of the view.

view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,100,200);

Comment: I do not want to use view.frame as I do wanted to make changes to UIView in drawRect or layoutSubView.

Comment: You may not need to change any things on UIView. Just draw the view into your destination context with proper width/height.

Comment: I am having a custom UIView. Can you elaborate on the drawing view in to the destination..

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 2.0);
```

Will make your view twice as high but the same width. However, transforms are applied after rasterisation so you'll just get the original pixels stretched out, you won't reveal any extra detail. You should also be aware, from the UIView documentation, that if transform is set to anything other than the identity then `frame` becomes undefined.

Comment: I Checked this. As you mentioned it was pixelated. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I'm not completely confident, but if you created a context with a suitable scale then used `renderInContext:` to get an image of the relevant view at an increased resolution, you might be able to work with that.